# Sequentially find the indexes of an element into a collection

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, functional-programming, generics

Util class to find into a collection the indexes of a given element with multiple occurrences from the first index or relative to a given index.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class NextIndex {

    public static <T> Lookup<T> of(T element) {
        return new NextIndex.Lookup<T>(element);
    }

    public static class Lookup<T> {

        private T element;

        private List<T> source = Collections.emptyList();

        private int fromIndex = 0;

        public Lookup(T element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        public Lookup<T> into(Collection<T> source) {
            this.source = new ArrayList<>(source);
            return this;
        }

        public Lookup<T> fromIndex(int index) {
            this.fromIndex = index;
            return this;
        }

        public int absolute() {

            int index = -1;

            if (fromIndex > this.source.size()) {
                return index;
            }

            for (int i = this.fromIndex; i < this.source.size(); i++) {
                if (this.element == this.source.get(i) || this.element.equals(this.source.get(i))) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }

        public int relative() {

            int index = -1;

            if (fromIndex > this.source.size()) {
                return index;
            }

            int i = this.fromIndex;
            while (i < this.source.size()) {
                if (this.element == this.source.get(i) || this.element.equals(this.source.get(i))) {
                    index = i - this.fromIndex;
                    break;
                }
                ++i;
            }

            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class IndexLookupApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int element = 1;
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> differentList = List.of(3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1);
        
        NextIndex.Lookup<Integer> indexLookup = NextIndex.of(element);

        int firstIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.into(list).absolute();
        int secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.fromIndex(firstIndexOfIntoAList + 1).absolute();
        int secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.relative();
        int indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList = indexLookup.into(differentList).absolute();
        int indexOfIntoDifferentList = indexLookup.into(differentList).fromIndex(0).absolute();

        System.out.println(String.format("list of elements [ %s ]",
                list.stream().map(n -> n.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));

        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %s is %s", element, firstIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("2st absolute index of %s is %s", element, secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("2st relative index of %s is %s", element, secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("different list of elements [ %s ]",
                differentList.stream().map(n -> n.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %s into a different list from previous index is %s", element,
                indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList));
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %s into a different list from the start is %s", element,
                indexOfIntoDifferentList));

    }
}
```

with the output:

```
list of elements [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 ]  
1st absolute index of 1 is 0  
2st absolute index of 1 is 3  
2st relative index of 1 is 2  
different list of elements [ 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1 ]  
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from previous index is 2  
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from the start is 2
```

Comment: What is the proportion of number of list changes, to number of element changes, to number of starting-index changes, to number of absolute/relative calls? If the number of list and starting-index changes is low, and the number of absolute/relative calls is high, then you should really consider making an index map.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you wrote this to use generics.

`of` and `into` represent a half-baked builder pattern. Builders in Java are useful because Java doesn't support named or default parameters, but they need to be written carefully to behave well. As it stands, your `NextIndex` - when constructed - is not useful, having an empty list; and can only be made useful via mutation (not good). You can also mutate `source` at any point but `fromIndex` will not be reset or validated (extremely not good).

A finer detail, but equally problematic, is that users familiar with the builder pattern expect to be able to reuse an intermediate builder before finalization; for instance, this sequence:

1. User constructs a `NextIndex`.
2. User calls `into(...)`.
3. User stores instance to two variables, `fromStart` and `fromMiddle`.
4. User calls `fromIndex(0)` on the first instance and `fromIndex(5)` on the second instance.

The user will get a nasty surprise if they don't realize that those are the same instance and one `fromIndex` has overwritten the other. Builders, before finalization, generally should return new instances after any parameter modification for this reason. Otherwise, surprise side-effects.

So - whether you separate your building logic into a different class or keep it in one class - make `source` and `element` `final`, and return a new instance from any method that changes `source` or `element`. Or, and this would be my preference given how simple the class is - drop the builder pattern entirely, and accept the source and element on construction (still making them `final`).

Don't name the member variable `fromIndex` to be the same as your parameter set method `fromIndex`; consider something like `baseIndex` for the variable.

`relative()` can be thin wrapper around `absolute()`, the former subtracting the previous index. Better, though, is to simply use sublist views and don't write any of the iteration yourself. While using a view, it's important to ensure that it isn't invalidated by mutating the underlying list, so call `Collections.unmodifiableList` on the constructor argument. This is cheap, and in fact a no-op if the list is already unmodifiable (which is the case for all lists in the demo).

Don't write an inner `String.format` when calling `printf`. Don't use `%s` for integers; use `%d`.

Write a utility method to format your lists, such as

```java
    private static <T> String fmtList(Collection<T> items) {
        String inner = items.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        return "[ %s ]".formatted(inner);
    }
```

But that produces output so close to the default `List.toString()` that it isn't worth rolling your own; just toss the list in directly.

`2st` is very funny, but should be written `2nd`.

### Suggested (simple class)

The following, to the best of my knowledge, is equivalent:

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static class Lookup<T> {
        public final List<T> source;
        public final T element;
        public int fromIndex;
        private List<T> view;

        public Lookup(List<T> source, T element) {
            this(source, element, 0);
        }

        public Lookup(List<T> source, T element, int fromIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            this.source = Collections.unmodifiableList(source);
            this.element = element;
            setIndex(fromIndex);
        }

        public void setIndex(int fromIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            view = source.subList(fromIndex, source.size());
            this.fromIndex = fromIndex;
        }

        public int relative() {
            return view.indexOf(element);
        }
        
        public int absolute() {
            int index = relative();
            if (index == -1)
                return -1;
            return index + baseIndex;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int element = 1;
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> differentList = List.of(3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1);

        Lookup<Integer> lookup = new Lookup<>(list, element);

        int firstIndexOfIntoAList = lookup.absolute();
        lookup.setIndex(firstIndexOfIntoAList + 1);
        int secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList = lookup.absolute();
        int secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList = lookup.relative();

        lookup = new Lookup<>(differentList, element, firstIndexOfIntoAList + 1);
        int indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList = lookup.absolute();
        lookup.setIndex(0);
        int indexOfIntoDifferentList = lookup.absolute();

        System.out.printf("list of elements %s%n", list);
        System.out.printf("1st absolute index of %d is %d%n", element, firstIndexOfIntoAList);
        System.out.printf("2nd absolute index of %d is %d%n", element, secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList);
        System.out.printf("2nd relative index of %d is %d%n", element, secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList);

        System.out.printf("different list of elements %s%n", differentList);
        System.out.printf("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from previous index is %d%n",
            element, indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList);
        System.out.printf("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from the start is %d%n",
            element, indexOfIntoDifferentList);
    }
}
```

### Build sugar

The following has build sugar kind of like what you were aiming for, but crucially, mutation semantics are different. Whenever you call a setter, a new instance is returned, with full validation of the new parameters and ability to reuse the previous instance if desired.

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static class Lookup<T> {
        public final List<T> source;
        public final T element;
        public final int baseIndex;
        private final List<T> view;

        public Lookup(List<T> source, T element) {
            this(source, element, 0);
        }

        public Lookup(List<T> source, T element, int baseIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            this.source = Collections.unmodifiableList(source);
            this.element = element;
            this.baseIndex = baseIndex;
            view = source.subList(baseIndex, source.size());
        }

        public Lookup<T> into(List<T> source) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            return new Lookup<>(source, element, baseIndex);
        }

        public Lookup<T> of(T element) {
            return new Lookup<>(source, element, baseIndex);
        }

        public Lookup<T> fromIndex(int baseIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            return new Lookup<>(source, element, baseIndex);
        }

        public int relative() {
            return view.indexOf(element);
        }

        public int absolute() {
            int index = relative();
            if (index == -1)
                return -1;
            return index + baseIndex;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int element = 1;
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> differentList = List.of(3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1);

        Lookup<Integer> lookup = new Lookup<>(list, element);

        int firstIndexOfIntoAList = lookup.absolute();
        lookup = lookup.fromIndex(firstIndexOfIntoAList + 1);
        int secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList = lookup.absolute();
        int secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList = lookup.relative();

        lookup = lookup.into(differentList);
        int indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList = lookup.absolute();
        int indexOfIntoDifferentList = lookup.fromIndex(0).absolute();

        System.out.printf("list of elements %s%n", list);
        System.out.printf("1st absolute index of %d is %d%n", element, firstIndexOfIntoAList);
        System.out.printf("2nd absolute index of %d is %d%n", element, secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList);
        System.out.printf("2nd relative index of %d is %d%n", element, secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList);

        System.out.printf("different list of elements %s%n", differentList);
        System.out.printf("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from previous index is %d%n",
            element, indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList);
        System.out.printf("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from the start is %d%n",
            element, indexOfIntoDifferentList);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
list of elements [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
1st absolute index of 1 is 0
2nd absolute index of 1 is 3
2nd relative index of 1 is 2
different list of elements [3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from previous index is 2
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from the start is 2
```