# Sequentially bidirectional find the indexes of an element into a collection (second thought)

Tags: java

Embodying the helpful tips from the [“Sequentially find the indexes of an element into a collection”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287768/sequentially-find-the-indexes-of-an-element-into-a-collection) previous code review resulted in extending the implementation to bidirectional index lookup, that is starting from first element  or starting from the last element.

Util class to find into a collection the indexes of a given element with multiple occurrences from the first index or relative to a given index. Used iteratively finds indexes of each occurrence.

Design patterns (1) fluent interface implemented by `Lookup.class` (2) builder with fluent interface implemented by `Explorer.class`.

The implemented sole concern is to find indexes of elements in collections. The parallelism, concurrency, thread safeness is an outside concern being achievable with each thread using its own instance of `NextIndex`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.function.IntSupplier;

public class NextIndex {

    public static <T> Lookup<T> of(T element) {
        return new NextIndex.Lookup<T>(element);
    }

    public static class Lookup<T> {

        private T element;

        private List<T> source = new ArrayList<T>();

        private int fromIndex = 0;

        private Explorer explorer = forwardExplorer();
        
        public Lookup(T element) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        public Lookup<T> into(Collection<T> source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return this;
            }
            this.source = new ArrayList<>(source);
            return this;
        }

        public Lookup<T> fromIndex(int index) {
            this.fromIndex = index;
            return this;
        }

        private Explorer forwardExplorer() {
            return Explorer.from(() -> { return this.fromIndex; })
                           .to(() -> { return this.source.size(); })
                           .bounder((index, bound) -> { return index < bound; })
                           .incrementer((index) -> { return ++index; })
                           .newIt()
                           .get();
        }
        
        public Lookup<T> forward() {
            
            this.explorer = forwardExplorer();
            
            return this;
        }
        
        public Lookup<T> reverse() {
            
            this.explorer = Explorer.from(() -> { return this.fromIndex > 0 ? this.fromIndex : this.source.size() - 1; })
                                    .to(() -> { return 0; })
                                    .bounder((index, bound) -> { return index >= bound; })
                                    .incrementer((index) -> { return --index; })
                                    .newIt()
                                    .get();
            return this;
        }
        
        public int absolute() {

            int index = -1;

            if (fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex > this.source.size()) {
                return index;
            }
            
            for (int i = this.explorer.from(); this.explorer.bounder(i, this.explorer.to()); i = this.explorer.increment(i)) {
                if (this.element == this.source.get(i) || this.element.equals(this.source.get(i))) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }

        public int relative() {

            int index = -1;

            if (fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex > this.source.size()) {
                return index;
            }

            int i = this.explorer.from();
            while (this.explorer.bounder(i, this.explorer.to())) {
                if (this.element == this.source.get(i) || this.element.equals(this.source.get(i))) {
                    index = i - this.fromIndex;
                    break;
                }
                i = this.explorer.increment(i);
            }

            return index;
        }
    }

    public static class Explorer {

        private final IntSupplier from;

        private final IntSupplier to;

        private final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> bounder;

        private final IntFunction<Integer> incrementer;

        public static Explorer.Builder from(IntSupplier start) {
            return new Explorer.Builder(start);
        }

        private Explorer(IntSupplier start, IntSupplier bound, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> bounder, IntFunction<Integer> incrementer) {
            this.from = start;
            this.to = bound;
            this.bounder = bounder;
            this.incrementer = incrementer;
        }
        
        public int from() {
            return this.from.getAsInt();
        }

        public int to() {
            return this.to.getAsInt();
        }

        public boolean bounder(int index, int bound) {
            return this.bounder.apply(index, bound);
        }

        public int increment(int index) {
            return this.incrementer.apply(index);
        }

        public static class Builder {

            private IntSupplier from;

            private IntSupplier to;

            public BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> bounder;

            public IntFunction<Integer> incrementer;

            public Builder(IntSupplier start) {
                this.from = start;
            }

            public Explorer.Builder to(IntSupplier bound) {
                this.to = bound;
                return this;
            }

            public Explorer.Builder bounder(BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> bounder) {
                this.bounder = bounder;
                return this;
            }

            public Explorer.Builder incrementer(IntFunction<Integer> incrementer) {
                this.incrementer = incrementer;
                return this;
            }

            public Optional<Explorer> newIt() {

                if (from == null || to == null || bounder == null || incrementer == null) {
                    return Optional.empty();
                }

                return Optional.of(new Explorer(from, to, bounder, incrementer));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IndexLookupApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int element = 1;
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> differentList = List.of(3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1);
        
        forwardLookup(element, list, differentList);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        reverseLookup(element, list, differentList);
        
    }

    private static void forwardLookup(int element, List<Integer> list, List<Integer> differentList) {
        
        System.out.println("********** Forward lookup **********");
        
        NextIndex.Lookup<Integer> indexLookup = NextIndex.of(element);

        int firstIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.into(list).absolute();
        int secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.fromIndex(firstIndexOfIntoAList + 1).absolute();
        int secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.relative();
        int indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList = indexLookup.into(differentList).absolute();
        int indexOfIntoDifferentList = indexLookup.into(differentList).fromIndex(0).absolute();

        String listToString = list.toString();
        System.out.println("list of elements " + listToString);
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %d is %d", element, firstIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("2nd absolute index of %d is %d", element, secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("2nd relative index of %d is %d", element, secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("different list of elements %s", differentList.toString()));
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from previous index is %d", element,
                indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList));
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from the start is %d", element,
                indexOfIntoDifferentList));
        
        int indexOf = indexLookup.into(list).fromIndex(0).absolute();
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
        while ( indexOf > -1 ) {
            indexes.add(indexOf);
            indexOf = indexLookup.fromIndex(indexOf + 1).absolute();
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("element's %d indexes in list %s is %s"
                , element
                , listToString
                , indexes.toString()));
    }
    
    private static void reverseLookup(int element, List<Integer> list, List<Integer> differentList) {
        
        System.out.println("********** Reversed lookup **********");
        
        NextIndex.Lookup<Integer> indexLookup = NextIndex.of(element).reverse();
        
        int firstIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.into(list).absolute();
        int secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.fromIndex(firstIndexOfIntoAList - 1).absolute();
        int secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList = indexLookup.relative();
        int indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList = indexLookup.into(differentList).absolute();
        int indexOfIntoDifferentList = indexLookup.into(differentList).fromIndex(0).absolute();
        
        String listToString = list.toString();
        System.out.println("list of elements " + listToString);
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %d is %d", element, firstIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("2nd absolute index of %d is %d", element, secondAbsoluteIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("2nd relative index of %d is %d", element, secondRelativeIndexOfIntoAList));
        System.out.println(String.format("different list of elements %s",
                differentList.toString()));
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from previous index is %d", element,
                indexOfFromPreviousIndexIntoDifferentList));
        System.out.println(String.format("1st absolute index of %d into a different list from the start is %d", element,
                indexOfIntoDifferentList));
        
        int indexOf = indexLookup.into(list).fromIndex(0).absolute();
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
        while ( indexOf > -1 ) {
            indexes.add(indexOf);
            indexOf = indexLookup.fromIndex(indexOf - 1).absolute();
        }
        
        System.out.println(String.format("element's %d indexes in list %s is %s"
                , element
                , listToString
                , indexes.toString()));
    }
}
```

with the output:

```
********** Forward lookup **********
list of elements [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
1st absolute index of 1 is 0
2nd absolute index of 1 is 3
2nd relative index of 1 is 2
different list of elements [3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from previous index is 2
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from the start is 2
element's 1 indexes in list [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] is [0, 3, 6]



********** Reversed lookup **********
list of elements [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
1st absolute index of 1 is 6
2nd absolute index of 1 is 3
2nd relative index of 1 is -2
different list of elements [3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from previous index is 5
1st absolute index of 1 into a different list from the start is 8
element's 1 indexes in list [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] is [6, 3, 0]
```

Comment: You're still mutating the current instance and attempting to use it in a fluent manner. This does not fix the issues called out in the previous review.

Comment: Also you've changed users. Be aware of the [rules around sockpuppet accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388984/what-are-the-rules-governing-multiple-accounts-i-e-sockpuppets).